# Use of defined/undef in Perl

Tags: perl

I am planning to pass two variables to a perl function, one of which may be optional. I am trying to check if the second one is defined or not, but it doesn't work correctly. When I called the function as myFunction(18), it assumes that the variable $optional is defined and goes to the else statement. But in the else statement when the $optional variable is being accessed it throws an "uninitialized" error. This is exactly opposite of what I have expected. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
sub myFunction {
    my ($length, $optional) = (@_);

    if (undef($optional) {
        more code..
    }
    else {
        more code...
    }
}

myFunction(18);
```

Comment: That's because the test for an undefined value is [`not defined`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html), not [`undef`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/undef.html).

Comment: If you're trying to find out how many are passed, then take the count of arguments: `scalar(@_)`.  If you call `foo(4,undef)`, you've passed 2 args.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The correct function is `defined`.  `undef` undefines `$optional`.  What you want to do is something like this:

```
sub myFunction {
    my($length, $optional) = @_;

    if (!defined $optional) {
        # Do whatever needs to be done if $optional isn't defined.
    }
    else {
        # Do whatever can be done if $optional *is* defined.
    }
}
```

Another way to deal with it (especially Perl 5.10+) is to use the "defined or" operator, `//`, like this:

```
sub MyFunc {
    my $length = shift;
    my $optional = shift // 'Default Value';
    # Do your stuff here.
}
```

What that does is detect whether the return value of `shift @_` is defined.  Since you already called shift once, we're now testing the second parameter.  If it's defined, assign the value to `$optional`.  If it's not defined, assign `'Default Value'` to `$optional`.  Of course you have to come up with your own sane default.

If you're stuck in the dark ages of pre-Perl 5.10, you could accomplish the same with:

```
my $optional = shift;
$optional = defined $optional ? $optional : 'Default value';
```

...or...

```
my $length = shift;
my $optional = defined( $_[0] ) ? shift : 'Default value';
```

Either way, I often prefer having a sane default, rather than a totally separate control flow path.  It's often a good way to simplify code.

Comment: `$SCALAR = undef;` just undefines. `undef(VAR)` does a lot more, even for scalars. (It frees various memory bits.)

Comment: @ikegami That's correct, but why complicate things?  I stuck with the behavior documented in `perldoc -f undef`.  Perhaps the word "just" is the issue.  I'll remove it.

Comment: `shift` shifts one element off the left hand side (the low-index side) of an array and returns that value. So `my $foo = shift @bar` reduces the size of `@bar` by one element, but taking the leftmost element and assigning it to `$foo`.  If no source array is provided, within a subroutine `shift` acts upon `@_`, which is where parameters are passed-in. Outside of a subroutine it acts upon `@ARGV` if no source array is explicitly provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
my $optional = defined( $_[0] ) ? shift : 'Default value';
```

This is dangerous code as it only shifts off the parameter if defined, if you had a third parameter this would get muddled when you call

```
MyFunc( 10, undef, 20 )
```